# Add file attachment to plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Can anybody help me?
I have this plug in, from here: https://github.com/agragregra/uniMail
It's perfect, but it don't support file attachment in form, only text inputs.
Here's code

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Thank you!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

and ofcourse code from mail.php

```
    <?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);
    $inp = trim($_POST["summary_file"]);


    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);


    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Answer (score 0):

## 3 steps: HTML, PHP & mail

This code cannot be easily adapted to add file attachments. You need to implement three steps:

Adding file inputs to a html form is quite basic. You can find examples all over the internet. This cannot possibly be a stumbling block.

Handling file uploads in PHP can be somewhat trickly, but is explained in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Your code uses the `mail()` function, which is quite basic. You will have to encode a multipart email, which is, if you find this difficult, beyond your capabilities. You better use something like PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which, believe it or not, makes this a lot easier.

Once you combine these three things you're ready to work with files. I think it's beyond Stack Overflow to do all this work for you. If you cannot do it yourself, you can hire somebody to do this for you.